# How to remove manually added backslashes in SQL injections?

Tags: php, html, mysql, stripslashes

I am using MySQL and PHP to manage my data on my website.

I have a paragraph typed in TeX format which so many mathematical formulas. I want to insert in my database and retrieve the same in some other place.

While retrieving I am using mathjax to display the mathematical part. 
Problem is while inserting the data.

When I am inserting the data

```
$\int f d\mu $ ( Note that this '\' is required to run the math formula)
```

I am getting the inserted data as

```
$\\int f d \\mu $
```

There two backslashes instead of one.

How to prevent the backslashes which are added every time with the manually added backslashes (which is required).

Will the `stripslashes()` help or any other solutions?

Thanks in advance.

```
<form action="" method="POST">



<input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $print->Id; ?> >

<table class="speaker-abstract" style="width:49%; float:left;">

  <tr>

  <th> Update the Abstract Details Here </th>
  </tr>

<tr>
<td>
<label> Title of the Talk </label>
<input  style="width:95%" type="text" name="title1"  value="<?php echo $print->title_of_the_talk1; ?>">
</td>


</tr>

<tr>
<td> 
<label> Abstract of the Talk (Type in TeX format) </label>

 <textarea style="width:95%" name="abstract1"  rows="10"  ><?php echo $print->Abstract1; ?></textarea>

 </td>

 </tr>

  </table>

  <table class="speaker-abstract" style="width:49%; float:left;">
  <tr>

  <th> If any other, update the Abstract Details Here </th>
  </tr>

<tr>
<td>
<label> Title of the Talk </label>
 <input style="width:95%" type="text" name="title2" value="<?php echo $print->title_of_the_talk2; ?>">
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td> 
<label> Abstract of the Talk  (Type in TeX format) </label>
 <textarea style="width:95%" name="abstract2"  rows="10"  > <?php echo $print->Abstract2; ?> </textarea>

 </td>

 </tr>

  </table>

 <input style="float:right;" type="submit" name="update_abstract" value="Submit/Update"> 

</form>
```

and the php code to submit the form and display the data is the following.

```
<?php

$success_msg="Updated Successfull !!!";
$search= "Search the Speaker Here";

if (isset($_POST['update_abstract'])){
$id=$_POST['id'];
$title1=$_POST['title1'];
$title2=$_POST['title2'];
$abstract1=$_POST['abstract1'];
$abstract2=$_POST['abstract2'];

$update=$wpdb->update( 
    'Invited_Speakers_auto', 
    array( 
        'title_of_the_talk1' => $title1,
        'title_of_the_talk2' => $title2,
        'abstract1' => $abstract1,
        'abstract2' => $abstract2

    ), 
    array( 'id' => $id )

);
if ($update==true){

echo $success_msg.$abstract1;

}else
{
 $success_msg="There is an error in the update";
}

}
?>
```

### PS:

1. Kindly note that, I need the slash which is inserted by the user, I just have remove the slashes which are automatically inserted while sql insertion happens.
2. `stipslashes()` Helps me in removing the added slashes in the output.

but I want to remove the backslashes while insertion itself.

Comment: Can we see the code?   You could preg_replace all slashes in the variable data and replace them with nothing to remove them. It's escaping the slash.

Comment: How are you inserting this data into your database and later displaying it?  Where are these extra characters coming from in the first place?

Comment: stripslashes will help you . it delete all added slash

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: Inside a double-quoted string you'll see those as being doubled, so maybe it's not a concern. What code do you use for insertion? How are you fetching the data? How are you displaying the fetched data? Using `stripslashes` is probably the wrong thing to do unless you're repairing damage.

Comment: I think if you use MySqli or PDO with prepared statement and placeholder, you don't need these backslashes or escaping characters.

Comment: @NMoeini Kindly explain.

Comment: @gloom, I have added my suggestion as an answer.

Comment: @NMoeini Dear Moeini, thank you for the answer. I am wordpress for my website, could you correct my code only since I am newbie for php and sql??

Comment: Updated my answer! Try to use `mysql_real_escape_string` or use `htmlentities` and then `html_entity_decode` when retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySqli or PDO with prepared statement. This is the best known method for sql injection prevention by the way. [Learn more about Sql Injection Prevention from this fantastic answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Following code successfully inserts the string into MySql Database and reads from it. Hope it helps!

```
 <?php
    $_user = 'root';
    $_password= 'root';
    $_db = 'localtest';
    $_host = 'localhost';
    $_port = 3306;
    $con = new mysqli($_host, $_user, $_password, $_db) or die(mysql_error);

    $new = '$\int f d\mu $';

        //insert into mysql table
        $sql="INSERT INTO test (math) VALUES (?); ";
        $stmt = $con-> prepare($sql);
        $stmt -> bind_param("s", $new);
        $stmt -> execute();

    // Reading From DB
    $id = 1;
    $sql="SELECT math FROM test WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt -> execute(); 
    $stmt->store_result();
    /* Get the number of rows */
    $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

    /* Bind the result to variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($new);

    if($num_of_rows < 1){ 
        echo "Can't find any record!"; 
        mysqli_close($con); 
        exit();
    }
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo $new . PHP_EOL;

        /* free results */
        $stmt->free_result();

    }
    mysqli_close($con); 
    exit();
   ?>
```

**Update**

If you can't use PDO or MySqli then `mysql_real_escape_string` can help you properly escape special characters.

You can also try to use `htmlentities` before inserting into database and then `html_entity_decode` when retrieved.